# Calculate difference between two datetime entities

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

[image]My Model is

```
public class abc
{
   public DateTime StartDate{get;set;}
   public DateTime EndDate{get;set;}
}
```

I have taken screenshot of my database columns. I want to display the difference of hours between StartDate and EndDate into my web application. How can I do that. I am using Entity Framework.

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate difference in hour by

```
TimeSpan diff = EndDate - StartDate;
double hours = diff.TotalHours;
```

and if `StartDate` and `EndDate` is `nullable` then

```
TimeSpan? diff = EndDate.Value - StartDate.Value;
double hours = diff.TotalHours;
```

Comment: I'm not getting this `TotalHours` property on an instance of DateTime type. Which .Net framework version are you using?

Comment: @RBT see my update hope this time there will be no problem

Comment: @Mostafiz This should be done in model or controller?

Comment: depends on situation, but in general better to do in controller

Comment: @Mostafiz What if I am using Linq and Lambda expression to access the DB entries?

Comment: then pull the data in controller using linq, and perform this difference operation using that data in controller

Comment: @Mostafiz TimeSpan diff = db.Table_1.Where(x => x.Id == 1).Select(x => x.EndDate.Value - x.StartDate.Value).ToList();

Comment: But still it shows me like cannot implicitly convert from System.Collections.Generic.List<System.TimeSpan> to System.TimeSpan

Comment: because you are pulling data using linq as a list, so either iterate over the list using foreach and perform difference or pull a single value using  `FirstOrDefault()` method at the end of select statement in linq query, if this can't help then show me your total cpode with linq query

Comment: System.ArgumentException: DbArithmeticExpression arguments must have a numeric common type.   It shows me this exception when I use          public ActionResult Index() { double hours; TimeSpan diff = db.Table_1.Where(x => x.Id == 1).Select(x => x.EndDate.Value - x.StartDate.Value).FirstOrDefault(); return View(hours=diff.TotalHours); }

Comment: try this code `public ActionResult Index()
            {
                double hours;
                var data = db.Table_1.Where(x => x.Id == 1).Select(x => x).FirstOrDefault();
                TimeSpan diff = data.EndDate.Value - data.StartDate.Value;
                return View(hours = diff.TotalHours);
            }`

Comment: inserted the breakpoint and checked. Value is still coming true in variable but when it comes to end of the method brace it shows me.....      The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Double', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Projects.Models.Table_1]'. But thanks a lot for your genius help. The code you wrote was easy and understand and hit the target in the most simple way possible.

Comment: ok great, the problem you asked for is solved I think now you just need to fix the model

Comment: @Mostafiz For me if the database entry is null then it's not working. I saw your above answer, that to insert "?" after timespan for any null datetime entry in database.  I tried doing the same but it shows me a red line under TotalHours, saying "TimeSpan? does not contain a defination for TotalHours and no extension method TotalHours accepting a first argument of type TimeSpan? could be found"

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the difference as:

```
var diffHours = (endDateTime- startDateTime).TotalHours
```

Comment: Nice! Taking a difference of two DateTime instances results in `TimeSpan` object which has this TotalHours property. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Another option can be adding `NotMapped` property to calculate it. Your model should look like this:

```
public class abc
{
   public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
   public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

   [NotMapped]
   public double HourDifference
   {
        get 
        { 
            return (EndDate - StartDate).TotalHours;
        }
   }
}
```

After getting data from database you can use `HourDifference` to display difference.

Comment: I am unable to use TotalHours in model

Comment: What do you mean by *unable to use*?

Comment: Thre should not be such a problem. Have a look at [this .net fiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vMUXtf).

Answer (score 0):

try this.. it will give you differnece of days..

```
TimeSpan tSpan = (abc.EndDate.Value).Subtract(abc.StartDate.Value);
var NoOfDays = tSpan.Days;
```